# Install collection dependencies in ansible with differing proxy settings

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy, ansible-collections

Problem: I want to install a collection via ansible-galaxy, but one needs a proxy and the other one does not

galaxy.html of the needed collection:

```
dependencies:
     community.docker: 2.4.0
     git+https://gitlab.test.org/collections/test: master
```

In this example, community.docker needs a proxy to be installed, the other one fails if a proxy is set.

Is there a possibility to unset the proxy or set the proxy for a dependency in the galaxy.yml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the no_proxy environment variable on the controller is a fine solution for this problem.

```
export no_proxy=gitlab.test.org
```

It can get rather aggregious to do this though if you have similar names for your gitlab instances, but worked for me.